# init the map but don't let it fit the screens view bounds

Tags: ios, mapkit, uinavigationbar

```
mapView =[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

this make the mapView on all the screen, so it hides my `UINavigationBar` how can i show my map without hiding it please ? thx in advance :)

Comment: where are you using this code? in a view controller or some where else?

Comment: yes, in a UIViewController, specifically in the viewDidLoad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one -

```
mapView =[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: i have made a sample project with navigation controller with a map view in its root view controller and its working fine with your code also, find it here - http://hotfile.com/dl/116700647/378dc63/test.zip.html

Comment: Hi, thx for sharing this great project, but my problem still there, all the screen is hided by the map :(

Comment: is my project running succefully at your end

Comment: Hi, i didn't understand you :)

Comment: i m saying that have you tried test.zip? is that working fine?

Comment: yes, it works fine and i have already use your code but i have always the same problem.